# Выполнение JavaScript через Java (javax.script)

Tags: javascript, java

Как требуется указать переход строки (\n), чтобы все заработало?
Мне нужно разбить полученный текст по строкам.

```
String  sbJs="";
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine rhinoEngine = manager.getEngineByName("javascript");
Bindings bindings = rhinoEngine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
bindings.put("parse_text", "aaaddd\n aaadd\n daadd a dffaww");
sbJs +="var result=parse_text.split('a')"; // если здесь вместо 'a' поставить '\n' то вываливается ошибка
rhinoEngine.eval(sbJs.toString());
NativeArray script_result =  (NativeArray) bindings.get("result");
for (Object o : script_result.getIds()) {
    int index = (Integer) o;
    System.out.println(script_result.get(index, null));
}
```

Comment: В JS слэш нужно экранировать. Попробуй '\\n'.

Comment: если этот скрипт выполнить в JS, то все работает

    <html>
    <div id="HeshKod"><b>ololo</b></div>
    
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    var parse_text="aaaddd\n aaadd\n daadd a dffaww";
    var result=parse_text.split("\n");
    document.getElementById('HeshKod').innerHTML = '<b>'+result+'</b>'; 
    </script>
    </html>

Comment: нашел 2 варианта как это сделать, а теперь интересно услышать Ваши варианты, не открывая свои :D

Comment: добавить второй слеш - \\n ? :) любопытства ради

Comment: Можно пояснить смысл:  

   String  sbJs="";
   ... sbJs.toString() ...
Зачем делать из строки строку? Мне самообразования ради.

Comment: )))) ни для чего, последствия копипаста. Изначально там был StringBuilder.

Comment: @DroidAlex пробовал, не работает. пробовал туда втулить символ через двойные кавычки при помощи экранации, тоже не канает. По идее java передает неправильный символ.

Comment: сам код символа неправильный? или в каком смысле? странно как-то, \\n - везде один и тот же перенос по идеи :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Постараюсь объяснить причину.
Имеем исходное выражение:

```
sbJs +="var result=parse_text.split('\n')"
```

eval получит что? Правильно:

```
var result=parse_text.split('
')
```

что есть ошибка синтаксиса.
Двойное экранирование спасет:

```
sbJs +="var result=parse_text.split('\\\n')"
```

тогда eval получит

```
var result=parse_text.split('\n')
```

---

Извините.
Двойным экранированием конечно будет

```
sbJs +="var result=parse_text.split('\\n')"
```

Простите, что предоставил Вам ошибочный ответ.

Comment: а почему тогда работает так :

    sbJs +="var result=parse_text.split(\n)";

Comment: @sonniy, без понятия. Баг или фича, но Ваша проблема в том, что я описал.

Comment: @ReinRaus за это спасибо, но ваше экранирование не дает "правильный вывод", при таком разделителе JS занес в Array каждую букву в отдельности, а не 3 части текста.

ЗЫ поменял экранирование `'\\\n'` на `'\\n'` и заработало ... а еще 5 часов назад не работало >_<'

Comment: @sonniy, извинился в ответе- неправильно сделал двойное экранирование.

Comment: @ReinRaus ничего страшного :), главное что разобрались и еще раз спасибо за Вашу помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Варианты которые мне помогли:

- Самый адекватный :

передать в JS аргумент

```
 bindings.put("separator", "\n");
```

а потом использовать его

```
sbJs +="var result=parse_text.split(separator)";
```

- Мне не понятен, но:

  sbJs +="var result=parse_text.split(\n)"; // да да, пишем вообще без каких либо кавычек

[[@DroidAlex](/users/2401/droidalex)](/users/2401/droidalex) Есть предположение что Java при использовании `rhinoEngine.eval` \n передает не корректно, так как сам JS выполняет этот же код нормально, а также то что переданный \n без кавычек проконал.

**ЗЫ**
почему я больше не могу комментировать свой вопрос? есть какой то лимит комментариев ?

**ЗЫ2** 
как же я ненавижу этот редактор текста :D